# Laravel connection with local SQL instance with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel, windows-authentication, sqlsrv

I am trying to establish connection with SQL Server local instance in Laravel. The SQL Server has Windows Authentication.

```
'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => 'SKILL....\SQLEXPRESS',
'port' => '1433',
'database' => 'dbname',
'username' => 'SKILL....\101...',
'password' => 'W.....',
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => false,
'prefix_indexes' => true,
```

Unable to establish connection.

Comment: have you changed your default driver to sqlserver? is sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv installed on server?

Comment: Windows Authentication doesn't use usernames and passwords. What are you actually trying to do with them?